# node request multi thread issue

Tags: node.js, request, node-async

I want to process first item('http://www.google.com') array2.foreach complete before start second item('http://www.amazon.com')
but request is support thread so this result is

```
http://www.google.com
http://www.amazon.com
http://www.apple.com
1
2
.
.
```

but I want to be

```
http://www.google.com
1
2
3
.
.
http://www.amazon.com
1
2
.
.
```

MyCode

```
var async = require('async');
var request = require('request');

var array1 = ['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.amazon.com', 
'http://www.apple.com'];
var array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

array1.each(function (item, callback) {

    console.log(item);
    aa(item, callback)

})

function aa(url) {

    request(url, function (err, res, html) {
        array2.forEach(function (item, callback) {
            //This part Current Page crawling
            console.log(item);
            sleep(1000);
        });
    })
}
```

how can I do that?

Comment: So do you want all your requests to be non-blocking? i.e. crawl those 3 sites asynchronously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added `async` module but not yet used. You need to use it, you may like to use `async.eachSeries()` function to achieve your need. Here is code that may help you

```
var async = require('async');
var request = require('request');

var array1 = ['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.amazon.com', 
'http://www.apple.com'];
var array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

function aa(url, callback) {

    request(url, function (err, res, html) {
        async.eachSeries(array2, function iteratee(item, callback2) {
            console.log(item);
            setTimeout(function() {
                callback2(null);
            }, 1000);
        }, function done() {
            callback(null)
        });
    })
}

async.eachSeries(array1, function iteratee(item, callback) {
    console.log(item);
    aa(item, callback)
}, function done() {
    console.log('completed');
});
```